# two divs with display:inline-block - second div with iframe ad being pushed down a few pixels

Tags: iframe, responsive-design, css

Background: working on a responsive redesign. normalize.css used for reset.
DFP Ads inserted into div's using [this technique](http://exisweb.net/how-to-use-google-adsense-on-a-responsive-website). The ad container div's are hidden depending on window size and the ad iframe's are only inserted once into the non-hidden div. I also have a site logo div, .brand, that is hidden or not depending on width. Both the ad div container, .ta, and the logo container, .brand, are contained within a div called .secondnav. All three divs are 90 px tall. .brand, #ldr and .ta are all display:inline-block.

When .brand is display:none, the iframe ad in #ldr div contained by .ta sits perfectly within the height of 90px.

When the window is a bit bigger and .brand becomes display:inline-block, .ta suddenly gets pushed down about 4-5 pixels. They're still side by side but suddenly the ad is a few pixels lower.

I can't see what could be pushing it down. I thought it could be how the div is interacting with the ad's iframe, but why is it only happening when it's next to another inline-block div?

Here's the CSS:

```
   .brand {
width:200px;height:90px;
background:#660000 url('/dh5.svg') no-repeat left top;
display:inline-block
}
.multiplebgs .brand {
width:200px;height:90px;
background-color:#fff;
background-image:url(/dh5.svg),url(/dhw.svg);
background-position:0 0,30px 0;
background-size:30px,170px;
background-repeat:repeat-y,repeat-y;
display:inline-block
}
.ta {
height:90px;
display:inline-block
}
.secondnav {
height:90px;
background:url('/fs.jpg') 0 0 repeat
}
#ldr {
background:blue;
width:728px;height:90px;
display:inline-block
}
#mldr {
background:yellow;
width:320px;height:50px;
display:inline-block
}
#smallban {
background:green;
width:468px;height:60px;
display:inline-block
}
```

Here's the html:

```
<div class="secondnav">
<div class="brand"></div>
<div class="ta">
<div id="ldr" class=
"adslot hidden-phone hidden-tablet visible-desktop" data-dfp=
"728x90"></div>
<div id="mldr" class=
"adslot hidden-desktop hidden-tablet visible-phone" data-dfp=
"320x50"></div>
<div id="smallban" class=
"adslot visible-tablet hidden-phone hidden-desktop" data-dfp=
"Smallbanner"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Wasn't sure if I could include an URL to my test page so you could see this in action. Will edit it and include one if it's kosher. Will Google more on iframe alignment but thought I'd ask here. Thanks.

My test is here: http://www.digitalhit.com/bptest/index.shtml The issue appears at any size where there is an ad next to the .brand. e.g. at 480px, 600px, 1024px or higher. Please ignore the garish colours, just there for seeing the divs clearly as I test the design.

Comment: Inline blocks get spacing weirdness from inter-element white space text nodes in some browsers, could check it's not a text node pushing things out of place.

Comment: Will remove the white space between the divs and see if that helps. One thing I did just notice: For some reason I tried reducing the height of .brand (the one with the background svg) one pixel at a time. When the height reached about 83 pixels the ad div next to it was perfectly aligned with its container's height. Confused why changing the height of the div next to it would make this difference. After all they're side by side. And it's not a solution because I want it 90, not 83px. :-)

Comment: @Klors removing the white space had no effect, unfortunately.

Comment: Post the URL, easier to see your problem.

Comment: Url added to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite Sergio's great suggestions, I couldn't get it to work for me, probably as I had no control over the HTML in the iframe ad from Google. Going back to floating the .brand div to the left and centering a width-defined div containing .brand and the ad divs worked for me and everything was vertically aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the iFrame:

```
style="border: 0px; top:0px;"
```

Comment: re-did my answer. Maybe this is what you needed.

Comment: Don't have direct access to the iframe as it's inserted by google, but will try .adslot iframe {border: 0px; top:0px;} in my css.

Comment: Added the css for the iframe but it appears that perhaps Google's inline styles are overriding it. I can't get it to shift.

Comment: just realized I can't get it to shift because the iframe is coming from another domain. Look's like I'll have to go back to floats as I didn't see the problem there.

Comment: last try: adding `!important` on your CSS

Comment: thanks for your help tonight. !important didn't work. Is setStyles Mootools? Is there a jQuery equivalent? Off to bed...6am here.

Comment: Google's DFP ad platform...and in turn then there's the 3rd party advertisers. So I'm beginning to think inline-block won't work in this use case.